# how do I convert a single char to a uint in a well defined way and cross platform way?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, undefined-behavior, static-cast

Let's say I have a single char:

```
char myChar = 'A';
```

and I want to populate an uint:

```
uint8_t myUint8 = 0;  // 0 is just a default;
```

is it well defined to do this:

```
myUint8 = static_cast<uint8_t>(myChar);
```

So in this case I would expect

```
myUint8 == 65
```

to evaluate to true.  Is this well defined?  Will this function cross platform?  If not how can I make it well defined and portable?

Update: While I would like to handle the problem of determining the encoding scheme and if uint8_t is available on target eventually, they are beyond the scope of this question, hence I would like to refine my example as follows:

```cpp
    char myChar = 'A';
    unsigned myUnsigned = 0;  // 0 is just a default;
    myUnsigned = static_cast<unsigned>(myChar);
    char myRoundTripChar = static_cast<char>(myUnsigned);

    printf("char is unchanged: %s", myRoundTripChar == 'A' ? "true" : "false" );
```

the desired output here is true.  This alternate example removes all the 'magic numbers' and possibly defined types I think to show the problem another way.

Comment: You can't expect `myUint8 == 65` to be true because `'A'` does not have to have the value of `65`.  Don't use magic constants, they will burn you eventually.

Comment: @NathanOliver Can you explain when this would not be 65?  I would be concerned if I sent this over the wire and they didn't have the same value.  Can the encoding used be something aside from utf8?  What determines what encodings are used?

Comment: Not everyone on earth uses ASCII. IBM, for example, has a plethora of hardware that still use [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), where `'A'` is `0xC1`, not `0x41`.

Comment: Not all systems can guarantee `uint8_t` either. I had the extreme pleasure of once getting to play with a computer that had 32 bit `char`.

Comment: Would you mind telling why would you need such conversion?

Comment: @Osyotr I receive some byte arrays that have data encoded in chars.  These are usually presumably text, but really the object blob is complex and could be many things encoded a variety of ways.  I want to log these chars as their raw numeric values.  The encoding *should* be consistent, but if this particular log triggers we received bad data and all bets about format are off.  I want to dump this data for debug purposes before we handle the error and attempt to recover so we can get a better idea of what might have caused it if it occurs.

Comment: The execution charset is not guaranteed to be ASCII-compatible: https://godbolt.org/z/7sfMczq36. But note that `static_cast<uint8_t>(u8'A') == 65` is guaranteed to be true.

Comment: @alrav ah, I see. If you have just `char const *`, then you might want to cast it to `uint8_t const *` to be 100% sure that you work with bytes (although platforms where char is not 8 bit are very uncommon).

Comment: @Osyotr that's the intent, but I am unsure of how to best go about it, hence the question.  I know just casting the pointer is bad as it invokes UB via strict aliasing violations... though maybe some kind of memcpy would be viable?  Not sure.....

Comment: @alrav casting to `char`, `unsigned char`, and `std::byte` does not invoke UB.

Comment: @Osyotr That is good to hear.  Does the bit layout change when converting the sign?  Like when casting as signed char to an unsigned char?